# Как отменить/удалить ввод данных в ячейке TableVew при использовании Qspinbox delegate?

Tags: python, pyqt5, tableview, делегаты, qspinbox

В модели ***TableView*** использую ***QSpinBox Delegate***. При активации ячейки автоматически отображается значение по умолчанию в ***SpinBoxe***, которое остается даже несмотря на отмену ввода, или удаления значения. Мне хотелось бы, что бы при отмене ввода или удаления значения,  оставалось пустое поле ячейки, после ее деактивации. Каким образом можно этого добиться?

Минимальный пример

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate, QSpinBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex) 

class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    signal_delegate = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)  

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        editor = QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda val, row=index.row(): self.update_editor(val, row))  
        editor.setFrame(False)
        editor.setRange(-360, 360)
        editor.setSingleStep(1)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        try:
            value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
            editor.setValue(int(value))
        except TypeError:
        pass

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
        editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = str(editor.value())
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)

    def update_editor(self, val, row):  
        self.signal_delegate.emit(val, row)  


class MyDelegateInTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()           
        self.sim = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(1,1) 
        self.table.setModel(self.sim)

        boxMain = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        boxMain.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(boxMain)

        delegate = Delegate(self)                                             
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)                    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowExample = MyDelegateInTableView()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Не совсем понятна ваша проблема. Можете попробовать сформулировать по-другому ваш вопрос

Comment: @Alexander Chernin
 При первом запуске таблицы, ячейки пустые. При установке курсора в ячейке (двойной клик), появляется значение в  spinbox. Даже если  не водить значение, (отменить), это значение  остается, поле ячейки остается заполненным. Так же и  с удалением...При попытке удалить значение, оно не удаляется...ячейка не пустая. Мне хотелось бы что бы при отмене ввода или удалении,  поле осталось пустым.

Comment: Логично. При запуске ячейки оно заполняется значением из модели (метод setEditorData), если вы отменяете ввод сразу же, то в ячейке будет показано то значение, которое у вас сохранилось в той же самой модели. Если у вас в модели для данной ячейки есть данные, то они и будут показываться. Если вы ничего не вводили, но вызывали QSpinBox, то думаю, что в модель может попадать значение по-умолчанию из QSpinBox (хотя?). Короче, надо смотреть как у вас выглядит модель